# Neo4J averaging numeric property over several nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, nosql

I have a large graph and exactly 2 days of Neo4J under my belt, i.e. zilch.

I want to compute an average over all nodes of a certain numerical properties, say `n.prop_01` whenever it occurs in nodes `(n)`. Then I want to get the nodes whose property `n.prop_01` is below a certain threshold depending on the average.

I could not find an answer or something inspiring in the documentation or on online forums. I tried what follows and more...

```
MATCH (n) WHERE exists(n.prop_01)
WITH n, collect(n.prop_01) AS all_prop_01
UNWIND all_prop_01 as all_prop
WITH n,prop_01,avg(all_prop) AS avg_prop
WHERE n.prop_01 < (1.1*avg_prop)
RETURN n.name,n.prop_01  LIMIT 20;
```

Result:`(no changes, no records)`.

Thanks for any pointers as to why this does not work and how I could make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first calculate the average, and then filter, otherwise when you unwind, the average is equal to the property of each node:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE exists(n.prop_01)
WITH avg(n.prop_01) as avg_prop
MATCH (n) WHERE exists(n.prop_01) AND n.prop_01 < 1.1 * avg_prop
RETURN count(n), avg_prop
```

Comment: +1 Tx. See comment under Dave's answer. Could you somewhat expand yrs by highlighting the advantage of proceeding with a sub-query instead of resorting to the (sometimes) necessary UNWIND curse ? I come from graphs (not from databases) and I have not found any well structured explanation as to their relative pros & cons. Or does this warrant another question from me ? Cheers.

Comment: @Cbhihe I think that in your case the advantage of my decision in the readability and clarity of the query. And most likely the performance should not be particularly different.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the average upstream when you are matching your nodes with `prop_01`.

You should also consider adding a label to the match to reduce the number of nodes your query needs to look through.

You can also collect the `n` nodes rather than just `prop_01` and use that in your unwind later.

```
MATCH (n:Add_A_Node_Label_Here)
WHERE exists(n.prop_01)
WITH collect(n) AS all_n, avg(n.prop_01) as avg_prop
UNWIND all_n as n
WITH n, avg_prop
WHERE n.prop_01 < (1.1 * avg_prop)
RETURN n.name, n.prop_01  
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: +1: Thank you Dave. I use labels in my real formulation. I simplified the pbm statement so the post would be clearer. Yr solution works, but makes use of collect() and UNWIND. At least as far as UNWIND is concerned, I (no doubt badly) understand that it is generally costly. For that reason I choose @stdob-- 's answer, which in addition to not resorting to UNWIND, has the other advantage of presenting a simpler subquery structure. I guess that from a DB topology point of view, there is no clearly better solution. It all depends on the nature of the graph. So again thank you.